# Passing an action through another view

Tags: xcode

I'm working on my game but I am stuck at this easy step and hoping that you guys will shine your light on me and guide me through.

I have two classes with xibs:  one of them is MainMenu, another is MainGame,

In MainMenu, I have action button that switches into the MainGame xib.

My request is, I want to make another action in the MainMenu that will take me to MainGame but instead of the current game mode I have, I want to make a let's say "hard" mode which will shorten the time.

Here's my code:

```
timeRemaining2 = 10.0f;
```

So, what exactly I want to know how to do is, how can I setup an action button in the MainMenu where if click it, it will take me to the MainGame mode where I can I setup:

```
if(hardMode) {
timeRemaining2 = 5.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're creating and presenting your MainGame view controller, so I'll leave that bit up to you.  But here is a basic explanation of how to set up an instance variable to set and hold the timeRemaining value.
In MainGame set up an instance variable.  MainGame.h

```
@property float timeRemaining2;
```

Remember to synthesize this (to get setters and getters for free) in your MainGame.m

```
@sythesize timeRemaining2;
```

In your MainMenu, set up two IBActions, and connect each to its relevant button in Interface Builder MainMenu.xib.  Then in your MainMenu.h

```
- (IBAction)easyTapped;
- (IBAction)hardTapped;
```

In your MainMenu.m, define what happens when those messages are called:

```
- (IBAction)easyTapped {
    //instantiate your mainGame view controller, or retrieve it's pointer from self. iVars or however you're doing it.

    mainGame.timeRemaining2 = 10.0f;  //sets the difficulty instance variable 
    //present the mainGame view 
}

- (IBAction)hardTapped {
    //instantiate your mainGame view controller, or retrieve it's pointer from self. iVars

    mainGame.timeRemaining2 = 5.0f;  //sets the difficulty instance variable 
    //present the mainGame view
}
```